# How to get the base 10 logarithm of a Fixnum in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, logarithm

I want to get the base 10 logarithm of a Fixnum using Ruby, but found that n.log or n.log10 are not defined. Math::log is defined but uses a different base than 10.

What is the easiest way to get the base 10 logarithm of a Fixnum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is

```
Math::log10 (n)
```

And there is also a property of logarithms that `logx(y) = log(y)/log(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation for module Math the answer is really obvious:

```
Math::log10(n)
```

This gives the base 10 logarithm of n.

Answer (score 0):

[Math.log10](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Math.html#M001197)(numeric) => float
returns base 10 log